# How do in app purchases behave in Pending Developer Release?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I recently finished the first version of an iOS application. I have several in-app purchases within it. When testing these, I always used a physical iPhone. Apple just approved the build for release and the app is now in "Pending Developer Release." As one last sanity check, I generated a promo code for myself on app store connect and downloaded the app onto my phone through the app store. I quickly noticed that the `SKProductsRequestDelegate` method is never fired and the list of in-app purchases is never downloaded from Apple's IAP server. This is similar behavior to when the app is run within a simulator: the IAP data is never loaded.

I am unfamiliar with how the "Pending Developer Release" stage impacts in-app purchases. Will they work as expected when I release the app to the public? Is there some change I need to make and resubmit?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue on Apple's end. I contacted support and something on their end had been messed up when they approved the in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should work seamlessly except for the charging (You won't be charged if your app is downloaded from outside AppStore). So trying to gather logs may help you in this case.